# include a txt file in GAMS - errors 140 & 36 in the first lines of my txt file

Tags: gams-math

I am a new user in GAMS and I am trying to include a txt file in my code, but I get the same errors (error 140 & error 36) in the first lines of my txt file again and again.
Could anyone help?

My code goes like this, and I have also attached the txt file

```
* define the set of asset classes
set n Number of returns /n1*n120/;

* define Tables, Parameters, Scalars
Scalar T /120/;

$INCLUDE prices.txt
```

Please note, that later in the code I need to use the data from the text file in an equation like this:

```
EQ1..     sum(n, p(n)*prices(n)) =e= price0*exp(r*time);
```

Thanks

[prices.txt file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCfMp.png)

Answer (score 0):

Your `prices.txt` does not contain valid GAMS syntax. What you need is something like this:

```
Parameter prices(n) /
  n1 455.5
  n2 44545.5
  /;
```